# Find remaining elements in the sequence

Tags: c#, algorithm, performance, console

everyone. I've this small task to do:

> There are two sequences of numbers:
>
> 1. A[0], A[1], ... , A[n].
> 2. B[0], B[1], ... , B[m].
>
> Do the following operations with the sequence A:
>
> 1. Remove the items whose indices are divisible by B[0].
> 2. In the items remained, remove those whose indices are divisible by B[1].
> 3. Repeat this process up to B[m].
> 4. Output the items finally remained.
>
> Input is like this: (where -1 is delimiter for two sequences A and B)
>
> 1 2 4 3 6 5 -1 2 -1

Here goes my code (explanation done via comments):

```
List<int> result = new List<int>(); // list for sequence A
List<int> values = new List<int>(); // list for holding value to remove

var input = Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
var len = Array.IndexOf(input, -1); // getting index of the first -1 (delimiter)
result = input.ToList(); // converting input array to List
result.RemoveRange(len, input.Length - len); // and deleting everything beyond first delimiter (including it) 

for (var i = len + 1; i < input.Length - 1; i++) // for the number of elements in the sequence B
{
    for (var j = 0; j < result.Count; j++) // going through all elmnts in sequence A
    {
        if (j % input[i] == 0) // if index is divisible by B[i]
        {
            values.Add(result[j]); // adding associated value to List<int> values
        }
    }
    foreach (var value in values) // after all elements in sequence A have been looked upon, now deleting those who apply to criteria
    {
        result.Remove(value);
    }
}
```

But the problem is that I'm only passing 5/11 tests cases. The 25% is 'Wrong result' and the rest 25% - 'Timed out'. I understand that my code is probably very badly written, but I really can't get to understand how to improve it.

So, if someone more experienced could explain (clarify) next points to me it would be very cool:

**1**. Am I doing parsing from the console input right? I feel like it could be done in a more elegant/efficient way.

**2**. Is my logic of getting value which apply to criteria and then storing them for later deleting is efficient in terms of performance? Or is there any other way to do it?

**3**. Why is this code not passing all test-cases or how would you change it in order to pass all of them?

Comment: How many elements are in A and B? And how big they are?

Comment: @Executor1909 There is no such info. The closes I've found is - "All input and output integer numbers are guaranteed to fit into four-bytes signed integer type". Also, the input is always positive integers.

Comment: Between step one and step two it is expected that values will get new indices, since other values are being removed. But in your code, they are not removed until the end.

Comment: @rici Thanks for the note but I actually tried to remove them once I find them and it didn't work out at all as indices change and the whole thing become a mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm writing the answer once again, since I have misunderstood the problem completely. So undoubtly the problem in your code is a removal of elements. Let's try to avoid that. Let's try to make a new array C, where you can store all the correct numbers that should be left in the A array after each removal. So if index id is not divisible by B[i], you should add A[id] to the array C. Then, after checking all the indices with the B[i] value, you should replace the array A with the array C and do the same for B[i + 1]. Repeat until you reach the end of the array B.

The algorithm:

```
 1. For each value in B:
       2. For each id from 1 to length(A):
                3. If id % value != 0, add A[id] to C             
       4. A = C
 5. Return A.
```

EDIT: Be sure to make a new array C for each iteration of the 1. loop (or clear C after replacing A with it)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've actually tried but for some reason adapted the logic the way you see it now. I'll give this approach a try once more.

Comment: Hi again. So I've tried to implement your suggestion and now I recall why I switched to removing approach. [link](https://pastebin.com/wXzdMXXM) That's the link to my implementation of your suggestion. Maybe I've done something wrong, but this approach doesn't work because it doesn't take into account indexes swapping and when B > 1. Let's say input is - "1 2 4 3 6 5 -1 2 3 -1". Output should be - "3 5". However it's actually - '2 4 6 5' (at least with my implementation of your suggestion linked abode). Please, correct me if I'm wrong in implementation or understanding but I can't understand i

Comment: Hopefully, I've finally managed to understand your problem, sorry for any trouble. I didn't understand when the indices should change.

Comment: Thanks! I'm very grateful for the time you spent on me. It's now actually working! And thanks a lot for the deep explanation.